# Uploading videos to specific Google account through YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, service-accounts

After hours of searching, i've did'nt found a solution yet.
The most relevant post i've found is : [Youtube API : Service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068433/youtube-api-service-account)

According to this part of the Google documentation : [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts)

That i've read is that YT API did not support Service Accounts, so i've found no other solution yet.

There is any way to uploading videos to specific Google (YT) account, without ask the users of my service to log to their Google account ? The fact is that I want to any users on my website can upload some videos in private mode to my Youtube account, but google, when creating the client though this portion of code :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$key = file_get_contents("some/path/to/".KEY_FILE);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
     $client->setAssertionCredentials(
          new Google_AssertionCredentials(
              SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
              array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'),
                $key
          )
     );
$client->setRedirectUri('some_url');
$client->setDeveloperKey('some_DEV_KEY');
```

request to my user to get logged in with his own Google account...

Any way to bypass this login request by enter my own credentials in the code ?

Sorry for not-so-good english, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution : use ClientLogin authentication.
That allow us to specify our YT credentials through this line :

```
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($youtubeEmail, $youtubePassword, 'youtube');
```

NB : The third parameter is the "id" of the service we want to connect to

I know ClientLogin is deprecated but this solution work. If there is any solution more secure and clean, let me know :)

Have a nice day

Comment: I doubt that someone would give you  his google password (access to his email, youtube and many other services) .

Comment: The point was to upload users videos through MY "public" google account. So i just need to input my password :)

Comment: aint this deprecated on youtube api v3?, so this wont work.. will it? @EricMartin

Comment: @DavidMauricio It is. But as mihai said in a previous answer, youtube fixed the CORS issue in V3 but they don't support browser based uploading anymore. Since i read that, I had to move to V2 api to fit my needs, so it's working.

Sorry for the late answer !

Answer (score 3):

Eric , It  is possible to do that if you use the  browser upload API ( V2 ) https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading . However it doesn't fully support CORS which means you can't show a progress bar and you must use iframes to handle the browser redirect. 
  Youtube [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4050) the CORS issue in V3 but they don't support browser based uploading anymore so they suck and you have to choose either to proxy the video upload through your server(I do this) or ask the user login with their google account. I think they did it on purpose to promote the plus service. After they 'fixed it' ( took about a year ) a guy @jeff showed a demo using  google plus to login ! what a joke !

Comment: Useful info, and a satisfying rant.

Answer (score 0):

It is by design that you can't easily do what you're wanting; you don't want to be liable for what other people upload through your app into your account. The best way to accomplish what you're after is to use something like [Youtube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/) -- users will upload videos into their own accounts with their own credentials, but it automatically will tie those videos into a playlist that you run off your own app (and it even gives you review capabilities over whether those videos should be included).

You can also roll your own solution that accomplishes the same kind of approach. Trust me ... at some point you'll be grateful that you can't just let anyone upload into your personal account!

Comment: Sorry but that's not the question... My need was to do this, so that's i wanted. To prevent flood upload i've set a security, a video can be uploaded each 10 minutes after the previous upload. 

However, thanks for your answer

Comment: @jlmcdonald  some people don't have google accounts or just don't want to log in through 100 websites to get a task done. You can pre-approve videos using the youtube API .

Comment: But if you rely on pre approving videos yourself, you're still liable, so if there's a copyright claim you're on the hook. If everyone uploads to their own account, they bear the liability. Seems a pretty risky thing to take on just because a user doesn't want to sign up for a free account... And if a developer is willing to take on that liability then he/she might be better off going with a different hosting solution, no?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other hosting solution such youtube.The encoding is just too expensive, not to mention the bandwidth costs and I doubt the performance would be any close to youtube. I guess you would do your best to filter copy right material and can't really see a tragedy if you have a copy right video on your channel. It can be removed upon request, right ? One in a million would be acceptable. After all Youtube itself doesn't do a good job handling copy right materials either.