# How to allow users to upload video from my website to my youtube account?

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to allow uses to upload video to my youtube account with v3 api? I want allow users to upload video through my website to youtube but not ask them to login to their youtube account. I know it was possible in v2 api. Is it also doable in v3 api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm digging into this question now, too. So far, one workaround is to use the email upload option (found within Youtube's settings once logged in).

There's a limit of 25mb here so it's probably just a temporary proof of concept but powerful enough for smaller vids (mixed with FFMpeg tools wrapped for the language of your choice, I'm using Node.js http://www.benfarrell.com/2012/06/14/morph-your-media-with-node-js/)

Ideally, I want a user to upload a vid, store it in RAM, and then get it pushed to my youtube channel. We'll see what we find...

Comment: hmm, seems like you are pointing towards mobile uploads? That might be a good solution. No api required at all just emailing the video would work. Nice catch. Will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've tried so hard to do the same thing as you /w the v3 API. The principal difficulty is to set our credentials in the code. With the v3 API, all the old login methods are "deprecated", to lead place to oAuth V2 login method.

In the API, i've didn't found a parameter where to set credentials. I hope you can find it. Let me know if this is the case.

If you success to create an httpClient object /w your credentials, this is perfect, the code is easy after doing this.

In the case you seach the right code for the v2 version : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405464/2353845)

Good luck :)